# cuda atomicAdd example fails to yield correct output

Tags: cuda

The following code was written with the goal of incrementing a 100 element array of floats by 1 ten times. In the output, I was expecting a 100 element array of 10.0f value for each element. Instead, I get random values. Can you please point out my error here?

```
__global__  void testAdd(float *a)
{
    float temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        a[i] = atomicAdd(&a[i], 1.0f);
    }
}
void cuTestAtomicAdd(float *a)
{
    testAdd<<<1, 10>>>(a);
}
```

My goal is to understand the workings of atomic operations, so as to apply them elsewhere.

Comment: I assure you that 'a' is correctly allocated to be 100 elements long, and initialized with 0 value for all elements.

Comment: To avoid race condition, In C++, I would use a mutex each time I read or wrote to the memory. What is the equivalent of that in Cuda?

Comment: Also, I am running this program on GTX 780 Ti, which I think ought to have high enough compute capability to support atomics. And I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have changed the properties for all .cpp and cu files (Device\Code Generation) to compute_35, sm_35 from compute_10, sm_10 earlier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's not how we do an `atomicAdd` operation.

Just do it like this:

```
atomicAdd(&a[i], 1.0f);
```

and the variable in question (`a[i]`) will be updated.

The *return value* from an atomic function is generally the *old* value that was in the variable, *before* the atomic update.

so doing this:

```
a[i] = atomicAdd(&a[i], 1.0f);
```

will update the variable `a[i]`, and then (non-atomically) assign the *old* value to the variable `a[i]`.  That's almost certainly not what you want.

Read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-functions):

> The function returns old.

The following complete code demonstrates correct usage:

```
#include <iostream>

__global__  void testAdd(float *a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        atomicAdd(&a[i], 1.0f);
    }
}
void cuTestAtomicAdd(float *a)
{
    testAdd<<<1, 10>>>(a);
}

int main(){

  float *d_data, *h_data;
  h_data=(float *) malloc(100*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, 100*sizeof(float));
  cudaMemset(d_data, 0, 100*sizeof(float));
  cuTestAtomicAdd(d_data);
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, 100*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    if (h_data[i] != 10.0f) {printf("mismatch at %d, was %f, should be %f\n", i, h_data[i], 10.0f); return 1;}
  printf("Success\n");
  return 0;
}
```