# Using atomic arithmetic operations in CUDA Unified Memory multi-GPU or multi-processor

Tags: cuda, atomic, unified-memory

I am trying to implement a CUDA program that uses Unified Memory. I have two unified arrays and sometimes they need to be updated atomically.

The question below has an answer for a single GPU environment but I am not sure how to extend the answer given in the question to adapt in multi-GPU platforms.

Question: [cuda atomicAdd example fails to yield correct output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729883/cuda-atomicadd-example-fails-to-yield-correct-output)

I have 4 Tesla K20 if you need this information and all of them updates a part of those arrays that must be done atomically.

I would appreciate any help/recommendations.

Comment: You can't do what you want with the generation of hardware you have

Comment: Tesla K20 (compute capability 3.5) do not support atomics beyond a single GPU, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions), with or without unified memory.

Comment: @talonmies I am on a cluster, I can request another node, so the generation of hardware is not a problem. Now, how can I achieve this atomic incrementation?

Comment: @RobertCrovella oh I see the guide now, thanks!!

Comment: If you have 6.x or better hardware, use the `_system` variants of the atomics.  It's in the programming guide I already linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize comments into an answer:

- You can perform this sort of address space wide atomic operation using `atomicAdd_system`
- However, you can only do this on compute capability 6.x or newer devices (7.2 or newer if using Tegra)
- specifically this means you have to compile for the correct compute capability such as `-arch=sm_60` or similar
- You state in the question you are using Telsa K20 cards -- these are compute capability 3.5 and do not support any of the system wide atomic functions.

As always, this information is neatly summarized in the [relevant section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) of the Programming Guide.