# atomicAdd - CUDA function

Tags: cuda

I apply atomicAdd function to add 10 in each array component
The results are Not identical to my expection.
Could you tell me why the value of list[1] is 12, while I expect 11=1+10. Total threads are 5. The initial array values are

```
slist[0]=1
slist[1]=2
slist[2]=3
slist[3]=4
slist[4]=5
```

the results are

```
list[0]= 1, list[0]= 1
list[0]= 1, list[1]= 12
list[0]= 1, list[2]= 13
list[0]= 1, list[3]= 14
list[0]= 1, list[4]= 15
```

```
__global__ void RunAtomicAdd(int* slist, int* val)
{
    int id = threadIdx.x;
    slist[0] = atomicAdd((slist +id), 10);
    printf("list[0]= %d, list[%d]= %d \n", slist[0], id, slist[id]);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cuda atomicAdd example fails to yield correct output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729883/cuda-atomicadd-example-fails-to-yield-correct-output)

Comment: Also your comment is confusing. `list[1]` is 12 because 2+10= 12. `list[1]` contains the value 2 in your example.

Comment: Thanks Ander, your answer is correct that list[1] should be 12. That is my mistake. Another question is why list[0] is not updated though the previous value at (slist+id) is not 1 when id>0.

Comment: I literally answered that below.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I wonder why that does not happen with the rest of the id, except id=0. could you explane again?

Comment: I literally explained that below..... your code does `slist[0]=` why do you expect others than `0` to change?

Comment: Let's see in case id=3. list[0] = atomicAdd((slist +3), 10) then i expect that list[0] = 4 (initial value), not 1. My question is why list[0] does NOT changed according to updated id.

Comment: Because you have a race condition, `list[0]` is not being updated atomically

Comment: There is no ordering among threads in CUDA.  Since all thread IDs write to `list[0]`, there is no reason to expect that only a particular value will show up there.  Do not assume that the write to `list[0]` happens at the same instant as the atomic update.  It does not.  The atomic is done first.  Sometime later, in each thread, each thread will try to write to `list[0]`.  There is no ordering as to which thread will win, or which value will show up there.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `atomicAdd` does not return the updated value, instead it returns the *old* value: [cuda atomicAdd example fails to yield correct output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729883/cuda-atomicadd-example-fails-to-yield-correct-output)

So all of your outputs are expected. In `slist[0]`, even if you update the value with `atomicAdd`, you immediately overwrite it with the output of `atomicAdd`, the old value. This does not happen with the rest of the `id`, except they do indeed store `1` in `slist[0]`, all of them.

You may want to have a new array to store the result of `atomicAdd`.